# Looking for a spider to crawl my website thousands of times to test ad distribution

Tags: php, web-crawler

Pretty straight forward.  We're implementing a new ad serving platform and it's paramount that the distribution of our ads are correct.

I've come up with a few solutions but one that I'd like to explore first is a spider that will hit my website thousands and thousands of times to ensure that this distribution is correct.

Any suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: I'd use a benchmark tool like [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) maybe.  Actual link check [Xenu](http://xenus-link-sleuth.en.softonic.com/) comes to mind.

Comment: You could look at `ab`, which will help with load testing. However, do you want to save pages as they are crawled? How do you plan to ensure that the distribution is correct?

Comment: Shall it follow links within your website? I have a [small crawler](https://github.com/taikano/deadlink-crawler) that can crawl a website, but you would have to adjust it a little maybe, as it can only handle very small websites at the moment. It's really, really basic only using a list to store URLs. Currently, it searches for deadlinks on a website.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just going to check one page or multiple?

wget under linux should be able to save the file quickly, as many times as you'd like. From there I'd grep part of the string you want to search for (http://adserver1.wherever.com) and show you a count. Most of this can be automated with shell scripting to make it fairly automatic.

Good Luck!